# Java URL droid crashing

Tags: java, android, url

I was told to ask this as a new question.

I have no idea how to do what I am doing, and I am just trying to hack something together really quickly.

But here's what I've got:

```
public void newScanThing(String scanFormat, String scanContent){
    URL u;
    try {
        u = new URL("http://www.searchupc.com/handlers/upcsearch.ashx?request_type=3&access_token=A98AC4EC-830D-4F6B-89D6-D6954361A8CA&upc=" + scanContent.toString());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
        String stringBuff;
        String scanData = "";
        while ((stringBuff = br.readLine()) != null){
            scanData += stringBuff;

        }
        br.close();

        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat + " DATA: I don't crash.");
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        // crash
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // crash
    }I know which line causes it to crash, and it is the scanData = new ... line. But I have no idea why. If you were to visit the link I visit, you would see the only thing in that URL is a single string. It's not even any HTML or anything, it's just a string.
```

Here is my function call:

```
 newScanThing("UPC_A","816983011311");
```

Anyways, what the heck am I doing wrong? I've never used this before. And I need to get this string for a proof of concept due in about 12 hours, and I have a lot of work to do after I get the string. So tips? Gestures at the right answer?

Maybe just a quick and dirty explanation of what I am doing wrong, how to do it right and why it works that way?

LogCat:

```
01-25 05:53:42.367: D/libEGL(13564): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:53:42.382: D/libEGL(13564): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:53:42.390: D/libEGL(13564): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:53:42.492: D/OpenGLRenderer(13564): Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 05:53:42.500: E/SensorManager(13564): thread start
01-25 05:53:42.507: D/SensorManager(13564): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA254 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41816ab8
01-25 05:53:42.593: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13564): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-25 05:53:54.406: D/AndroidRuntime(13564): Shutting down VM
01-25 05:53:54.406: W/dalvikvm(13564): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4106a2a0)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.newScanThing(MainActivity.java:60)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 05:54:02.820: I/Process(13564): Sending signal. PID: 13564 SIG: 9
01-25 05:54:10.656: D/libEGL(13768): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:54:10.664: D/libEGL(13768): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:54:10.671: D/libEGL(13768): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:54:10.781: D/OpenGLRenderer(13768): Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 05:54:10.789: E/SensorManager(13768): thread start
01-25 05:54:10.789: D/SensorManager(13768): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA254 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41813160
01-25 05:54:12.187: D/AndroidRuntime(13768): Shutting down VM
01-25 05:54:12.187: W/dalvikvm(13768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4106a2a0)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.newScanThing(MainActivity.java:60)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 05:55:03.835: D/dalvikvm(13768): GC_CONCURRENT freed 245K, 9% free 7464K/8199K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 44ms
01-25 05:57:28.851: D/dalvikvm(13768): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 11% free 7572K/8455K, paused 16ms+2ms, total 63ms
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the other post.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it to work, alright. Quick question: I want to do the line formatTxt.setText("...") in my new class, but formatTxt is in my old class. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error you get (`NetworkOnMainThreadException`) means that you are trying to do network operations on the main thread, which is not authorized anymore.

One solution is to execute all the network related operations in an `AsyncTask`. You have a good example on the link provided by Henry : [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Basically, you will create a class that inherits `AsyncTask`, in the `doInBackground` method of this class you will do your network operations, and in `onPostExecute` of the same class you will do the post treatment. You will call this class by creating an new instance and calling `.execute()`.

Comment: Ok, I did this, but now my line: formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat + " DATA: " + scanData); is broken. I think it's because formatTxt is part of my other class, in the other java file. How can I edit another class's stuff?

Comment: You could declare your `EditText` as a member of your main class, and initialize it like you did before. Then declare your `AsyncTask` in the same file as your main class, as an inner class, and you will have access to your `EditText`

Comment: Or you could pass your `EditText` as an argument of your `AsyncTask`. Not sure what is best though

Comment: I guess you finally got your answer in the other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352488/java-edit-textfield-in-another-class ;)