# java edit textfield in another class

Tags: java, android

I have class A and class B. Class A calls class B here:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    //respond to clicks
    new MyTask().execute();
```

In this new task, I do some network junk, and end up finding a string that I want to pass back to class A.

But I can't seem to do it. I tried to do something like classA.textfield.setText(text), but that didn't work. And it looks like classes can't return values, either. I've seen a few of the thing marked as similar, but I don't think they solve my issue, and if they do, I didn't understand how to implement them. I feel like this must have a super simple way to do it, but the only thing I've seen suggested that sound even remotely similar is making a new version of Class A, but that sounds horribly wrong...

Comment: Use a callback: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the `Callback` or `ActionListener` coding pattern shows it's strength.

In your MyTask class add this after the class declaration:

```
public interface MyTaskActionListener{
    public void didFinish(String result);
}
```

Add a member to your MyTask class:

```
private MyTaskActionListener listener;
```

Now, add a method `setActionListener` to MyTask:

```
public void setActionListener(MyTaskActionListener l){
    listener = l;
}
```

Next, before starting the MyTask, set the listener:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.setActionListener(new MyTaskActionListener(){
    public void didFinish(String result){
        yoirTextView.setText(result);
    }
});
```

Last but not least, call didFinish() in MyTask's onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    listener.didFinish(result);
}
```

Comment: What is onPostExecute? Where is that at? I think I put all the things where they go.

Comment: Just copy the onPostExecute I have added to my answer and paste it into your MyTask class.

Comment: Ok, the errors I get are: listener cannot be resolved (in the postexecute) ; MyTaskActionListener cannot be resolved to a type (from the line task.setActionListener(...)) ; The method setActionListener(MyTask.MyTaskActionListener) in the type MyTask is not applicable for the arguments (new MyTaskActionListener(){})

Comment: 1. Did you add the member `listener` to MyTask as explained? 2. And 3. either correct your imports or change to MyTask.MyTaskActionListener.

Comment: Like this?

  public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

 
 public void setActionListener(MyTaskActionListener l){
     listener = l;
 }
 private MyTaskActionListener listener;

Comment: Yes. Also change AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> to AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> and add @Override in the line before onPostExecute.

Comment: Should onPostExecute be protected? My IDE suggests it. Also, protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { in MyTask insists it cannot be void. Should it be String? It's set to return null, currently.

Comment: Yes, why not make it protected... Yes, it should be String. Make sure you call `return yourResultString` at the end of doInBackground.

Comment: My desired return value is called scanData, but when I type it in, it says it cannot be resolved as a variable. I think it's because I am not passing it into the doInBackground. -> protected String doInBackground(Void... params)

Answer (score 0):

Make a method in class B that allows you to modify the textfield and call that method in class A on a class B object(you should declare the textfield as a data member)
Otherwise you can set the visibility of the textfield(must be declared as a data member)  to public which is a bad practice

Comment: What? What does this MEAN?

Comment: I am not quite familiar with android and didn't notice the android tag. But if it is the same as dealing with GUI in java, you can make a method getTextField in class B that returns the textField you want and you can deal with it in class A.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a constructer in your class like the following :

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        TextView textView;

        public MyTask(TextView tv) {
            this.textView = tv;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }
```

As you can see you change the value of your TextView in the onPostExecute method .

and you call it from anywhere like the following :

```
new MyTask(tv).execute();
```

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score -1):

use a listener interface.

```
public interface CompleteListener{
  public void onComplete(String result);
}

public class A implements CompleteListener{

   public void onComplete(String result){
      // do something
   }
}

public class B extends AsyncTask {
    CompleteListener listener;

   public B (CompleteListener listener){
       this.listener = listener;
   }

   onPostExecute(String result){
      listener.onComplete(result);
   }

}
```